# How to parse a JSON formatted string in Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-synapse, sql-data-warehouse

T-SQL has a couple of functions that can parse JSON data, but none of them are applicable to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

I have data in JSON format in a VARCHAR column that looks like:

```
{'Purpose': 'Purpose 1', 'Activity': 'This activity'}
```

I could extract the 'Purpose' field in SQL Server by using the `JSON_VALUE` function:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{'Purpose': 'Purpose 1', 'Activity': 'This activity'}', '$.Purpose');
```

But this is not supported in SQL Data Warehouse. Is there a way to do this in SQL Data Warehouse?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql

Comment: FYI - this is in preview now. Soon you'll be able to use the JSON functions just as you currently do in SQL Server.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-data-warehouse-releases-new-capabilities-for-performance-and-security/

Answer (score 0):

**Update June 2019:**
This feature is in preview as at end of May 2019:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-data-warehouse-releases-new-capabilities-for-performance-and-security/

You should still consider if this is appropriate to do in your expensive Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

---

No.  Do this kind of processing in Azure SQL Database which does actually support JSON processing.  Start here:

**Getting started with JSON features in Azure SQL Database**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-json-features

You should also read this SQL Data Warehouse patterns and anti-patterns article.  Consider if your expensive MPP is the right place for this type of processing:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2017/09/05/azure-sql-data-warehouse-workload-patterns-and-anti-patterns/

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to do in Azure SQL Database because the data come from an external data source.

Comment: Another option might be ADLA / USQL which supports JSON processing (with only a little customisation).  Process it with USQL, pop it out into ADLS as a flat file, pick up in Warehouse with Polybase (if the volume genuinely justifies use if SQL DW).

Comment: @wbob I disagree Since Azure DW is so heavily dependant on ELT they should enhance it to support the JSON I could also see json being useful for storing logging information about the ELT process itself: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/13580676-add-support-of-json-format